# Presta - display feature and value on any page

Tags: html, css, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Can you show me how to display feature and value on any page? I tried to copy this part of code from product.tpl but it shows nothing :(

On product page (product.tpl) I use:

```
<div id="information">
<!-- Data sheet -->
<section class="page-product-box">
    <h3 class="page-product-heading informacje-heading">{l s='Data sheet'}</h3>
    {foreach from=$features item=feature}
        {if isset($feature.value)}
            <p><span class="information-feature-name">{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}: </span><span "information-feature-value">{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</span></p>
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
</section>
<!--end Data sheet -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution: [Display Features in Product List & Product Page](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/318019-display-features-in-product-list-product-page/)
It works but I don't want to display them on home page but both (home page and category page) using the same file - "product-list.tpl".

How can I turn off that code or hide just for home page?

Regards

**EDIT**
Ok, I wrote that code:

```
{if $page_name != 'index'}
<div class="features">
    {foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
        <div>
            <span>{$feature.name}: {$feature.value}</span>
        </div>
{/foreach}
</div>  
{/if}
```

Comment: Since PS forum is just redirecting all the old posts back to the homepage, I appreciate the code block example.. & confirm it works great for 1.6.1.24